# Benefits of Null Safety

Tags: null, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I've read that it seems to be the best invention after the wheel. That makes me suspicious anyway, certainly because I didn't understand everything the concept implies.

To resume what I understood, before we had `NullPointerException` so a very clear idea about something is wrong in the code and where the problem occurs but not where the null was set. Anyway, it was quite clear that we could wait here until the null pointer comes back expecting understand what happened from the backtrace. Everybody did that already, that's never impossible to find.

Now with Null Pointer Safety, we do not have such crash anymore, just some part the code which silently won't be executed in our application (we assume the reference used is not supposed to be null as before, of course), causing maybe strange behavior even more complicated to understand than the `NullPointerException` before, or maybe just some tasks not executed for month before someone realize it.

Is it the benefits Null Pointer Safety offer?

Comment: Nope, it gives you the power to be safe, however you can still handle yourself all the cases. My experience is that in some situation it is a pain in the ass with handling all the null checks, but this is mostly because of wrong architecture of the project rather than Null Safety.

Comment: @J.D.1731 ok, but an exception quickly tells you that something is wrong whereas null safety pushes the problem under the hood.

Comment: I add to the fact that if you want, you can still throw the NPE if you don't want it to fail silently or don't want to do anything different if the value is null

Comment: Null Safety doesn't push the problem under the hood. It gives you a chance to handle any null pointer before you actually use it.

Comment: If you're using null safety incorrect, yes, you could be in a trouble at runtime without NPE. Compiler force you to handle that, but not tell you how to do this.

Comment: do you agree that `NullPointerException` only occurs on bug. If I handle it correctly in Java I never be importunated by any null.

Comment: Yes, but in Java you have to check if everything is null. And sometimes what you don't expect to be null just is, and you crash your application

Comment: Null safety is a good way to swap a runtime error for a compile time error

Comment: When people more educated than me are saying that it's good, then it should be. But there is a learning curve that I am hating. And, it's not learning a new thing, but unlearning the old style of param passing that was being used. Programs that were compiling and running smooth yesterday are now popping a hell of a lot of errors. In my opinion, the program should catch and resolve the null errors by itself at run time. This task shouldn't have passed down to the programmer and asked him not to pass null... [Disclaimer: I am learning null safety. I may change my opinion later :P ]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will assume that you come from Java, you already looked at some explanations somewhere else and did not fully understand them. Therefore, I will not try to give you a comprehensive explanation (which you can find elsewhere) but instead I will try to make clear the core idea of null pointer safety.

There are two points that, if you understand them, should make it clear enough. First, there is the idea of having two separate types to represent what you would model as a single type in Java: nullable ones and not nullable ones. To give you an example, while in Java you put a string in a `String` object, without caring if the string can be null or not, in Kotlin you have two types: `String?` and `String`. The first accepts null values (like the Java equivalent) but the second does not. So you can have null values in types with a `?` (like `String?` or `Int?`) but there are a lot of restrictions on what you can do with those: basically you are restricted to the things you can do with a null, because, after all, the variable could be holding a null value. So no calling of method on it, for instance. So, while in Java you could call a method on it and have a `NullPointerException` sometimes, in Kotlin you cannot call any methods. And this is not because of some silent behavior of Kotlin, it’s much simpler than that: the compiler won’t let you. Try and you will see that the program does not compile. If the variable was of type `String` instead of `String?` then Kotlin would allow you to call methods from it.

So, basically, no null pointer exceptions because you can never call a method on an object variable that could be null.

But then, sometimes the variable is not null: so how could you call the method on the variable in those cases where the variable is not null? Again, the answer is simple: you have to check it. I mean, you have to use an `if` instruction (explicitly or implicitly) that will check if the variable is null or not. Something like “`if (myVariable != null) {call method on variable}`”. So, as you can see, the Kotlin compiler is clever enough to see that you used an `if` instruction that guarantees that the variable is not null, so it will let you call methods on the variable in the block between `{` and `}`. In other words, if your variable is of type `String?` but you are inside an `if` block where you checked that the variable is not null, Kotlin will treat it like a variable of type `String` instead of `String?`

When you speak about

> some part the code which silently won't be executed

I am guessing you are thinking about some operators that have an implicit `if` inside of them, like the `?.` operator. If you write

`myVariable?.call()`

it means roughly

`if (myVariable != null) { myVariable.call()}`

So, indeed, if the variable is null, it will “fail” silently. But this is not different than Java if you use the same kind of `if`. In other words, nothing will happen if the variable is null because you explicitly coded it to behave like that.

Answer (score 5):

The main benefit is that the code which can potentially cause a `NullPointerException` **does not compile**. The only situation when you get "part of code which silently won't be executed" is when you use safe calls to deal with a potential nullability error. This is not the only, and not the most useful, way to deal with such errors.

Answer (score 3):

To give you a short answer, your understanding is totally correct. Kotlin does not *solve* the NPE issue. It just proactively forces you to make an explicit decision to prevent it or not.

Answer (score 2):

## How null safety protects you from problems

In most languages, this would be allowed

```
val example: String = null
```

then later on you would do this:

```
print(example.toUpperCase());
```

You can see that the mistake is probably in the first bit of code, but the error happens at the second bit, which is confusing.

With null safety, when you define a variable you say if it will be null or not, and get a compilation (rather than runtime) error when this is broken.

## How to get a NullPointerException in Kotlin

It is still possible to get a null pointer, but the main way would be like this:

- Create a nullable type

  ```
  var r:String
  ```
- Have the value as null

  ```
  r = null
  ```
- Assert the value is not null

  ```
  r!!
  ```

This is why you want to avoid `!!` unless you are sure the value will not be null.

## Working with nullable types

You can deal with nullable types when you don't want null in many ways:

- With a default

  ```
  val set = nullable ?: "It was null, sorry"
  ```
- Throwing if the value is null

  ```
  val set = nullable ?: throw AssertionError(":(")
  ```
- Propagating nulls

  ```
  val set = nullable?.doThing()?.doThing2()?.property
  ```

  *set will be the final value, or null if any of these gives back a null*
- Only operating on nulls

  ```
  nullable?.let {
       print(it.property)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to not execute some piece of code due to a null object.

The benefits to a Null Pointer Safety system is that you can know beforehand if you might face a `Null Pointer`, and act accordingly. You can know for sure if something might be null, and do something different.

For example:

```
var nullableServiceVariable: NullableService? = null   //Let's say that you initialize this somewhere

var serviceAnswer = nullableServiceVariable?.answer ?: "Answer for null!"
```

The compiler makes you handle the possibility of `null`, so you don't get an unexpected NullPointerException that stops all your application. If the nullable is indeed null, I'll give an alternative branch, so that my system is still functional.

---

If you want, you can throw a `NullPointerException`, but it would be better to use a non-nullable variable instead:

```
var serviceAnswer = nullableServiceVariable!!.answer
```

`!!` will throw a NPE for you if the variable is null.